# Having issue assigning roles on guildMemberUpdate discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a discord bot for a server with third-party age verification, after their update with the verified role being added.

I wanted to then apply another role depending on a separate identifying role. But I keep getting problems with parts of the code being undefined or not a function, so I'm really stuck.

[image: picture of code]

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(oldMember.roles !== newMember.roles) {
      if(newMember.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Verified")) {
        if(newMember.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Workshop Devotee")) {
          let role1 = newMember.guild.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "Verified Workshop Devotee");
          newMember.guild.cache.get(newMember.author.id).roles.add(role1);
        }
        else if (newMember.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Workshop Helpers")) {
          let role2 = newMember.guild.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "Verified Workshop Helpers");
          newMember.guild.cache.get(newMember.author.id).roles.add(role2);
        }
        else if (newMember.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Workshop Supporters")) {
          let role3 = newMember.guild.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "Verified Workshop Supporters");
          newMember.guild.cache.get(newMember.author.id).roles.add(role3);
        }
        else{
          return;
        }
```

Comment: *I keep getting problems with parts of the code being undefined or not a function*  Can you be more specific about this, which *parts* / lines of code return undefined or not a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major errors with this code which is why it isn't working.

First of all, you are using the `.some()` method to fetch a `role` object, however `.some()` only checks to see if an item exists in a list, and returns true or false. Instead, you should use the `.get()` method to fetch the role.

```js
let role1 = newMember.guild.roles.cache.get(role => role.name === "Verified Workshop Devotee");
```

The other error I can see, is where you are getting the `member` object to add the role. You are for some reason trying to fetch a `guild` object using `newMember.author.id` which is the ID of a member, so this will return an error. Instead you can write

```js
newMember.guild.members.cache.get(newMember.author.id).roles.add(role1);
```

However, this code is also redundent as you already have the `member` object of the member you are adding roles to - its `newMember`. Therefore, you can instead write

```js
newMember.roles.add(role1);
```